# How to fill in a Docker mongodb image

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, docker

I don't really understand how I can fill in my mongodb image with a simple script like demoInstall.js.

I have my image and I can launch a mongodb instance. But I can not access to the docker image "mongo shell" to fill this one with the script.

I tried this command :

```
sudo docker run --entrypoint=/bin/cat mongo/ubuntu /tmp/devInstall.js | mongo --host IPAdress
```

But it's using the local mongo and not the image :/

Finally my aim is simple, I need to pull my image on a virgin server and launch a basic bash script who fill some informations in the Docker db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you use does pipe on the output of the docker locally. You might call with explicit `bash -c` instead:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm mongo/ubuntu /bin/bash -c '/bin/cat /tmp/devInstall.js | mongo --host IPAdress'
```

I am not sure the IPAdress will be available though. You might want to define it via environmental parameter or container linking.

Answer (score 0):

I would mount a volume with this argument:

```
-v /local_init_script_folder:/bootstrap
```

And then with a similar commandline like you proposed, you cann access the contents of the folder as `/bootstrap` from within the container.